# Remove The duplicate data in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

so, I want to print days in a month which is 1 to 31 and with the corresponding time in and time out value in MySQL, but it duplicates the value in data grid view.

how to can get rid of this duplicate value?

```
Sub loadtable()
        open_connection()
        '" & login.txt_identifier.text & "'


        Try
            Dim cm As Date = Now
            Dim Month As String = "MMMM"
            Dim query As String = "SELECT Day , Time_in ,Time_out FROM sample_work_hours WHERE student_number = '" & login.txt_identifier.Text & "' AND month = '" & cm.ToString(Month) & "' "
            insert_data.Connection = connect_data
            insert_data.CommandText = query



            adapter.SelectCommand = insert_data
            table.Clear()
            adapter.Fill(table)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = table

            DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Day"
            DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Time In"
            DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Time Out"

            For row As Integer = 1 To 31

                Dim newrow As DataRow = table.NewRow
                newrow(0) = row

                Dim dayDataRow As DataRow() = table.Select("Day = '" & row & "'")
                If dayDataRow.Length > 0 Then
                    newrow(1) = dayDataRow(0)("Time_in") ' Set the Time_in value
                    newrow(2) = dayDataRow(0)("Time_out") ' Set the Time_out value
                Else
                    newrow(1) = "" ' Set empty string if no corresponding day data found
                    newrow(2) = "" ' Set empty string if no corresponding day data found
                End If

                table.Rows.Add(newrow)


            Next


            connect_data.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

[image: heres the images of data grid view]

Answer (score 1):

Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT Day , Time_in ,Time_out FROM sample_work_hours WHERE student_number = '" & login.txt_identifier.Text & "' AND month = '" & cm.ToString(Month) & "' "

Comment: same output on my data gridview

Comment: try the query in mysql, make sure data not duplicate. solve it there, not in the vb datagrid

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i just solve it by customize the columns and add the specific data for it by checking the day

```
For row As Integer = 1 To 31

                 Dim newrow As New DataGridViewRow()
                newrow.CreateCells(DataGridView1)
                newrow.Cells(0).Value = row

                Dim dayDataRow As DataRow() = table.Select("Day = '" & row & "'")

                If dayDataRow.Length > 0 Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row, dayDataRow(0)("Time_in"), dayDataRow(0)("Time_out"))
                Else
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row, "", "")
                End If


            Next

            connect_data.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

i remove this code

```
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table

        DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Day"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Time In"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Time Out"

If dayDataRow.Length > 0 Then
                newrow(1) = dayDataRow(0)("Time_in") ' Set the Time_in value
                newrow(2) = dayDataRow(0)("Time_out") ' Set the Time_out value
            Else
                newrow(1) = "" ' Set empty string if no corresponding day data found
                newrow(2) = "" ' Set empty string if no corresponding day data found
            End If
```

and add this since i want to customize the data in grid view

```
            Dim newrow As New DataGridViewRow()
            newrow.CreateCells(DataGridView1)
            newrow.Cells(0).Value = row
```